# How to use GetMiddleware to stop route?

Tags: flutter, dart, router, flutter-getx

***get:4.6.5 or 5.0.0-beat.52***

I have a Verify the password page， and when I submit the right password, it will run a function from the last page. Like:

```
Get.toNamed(GetTest1Page.name, arguments: () {
   Get.toNamed(GetTest3Page.name);
});
```

And the `GetTest2Page` is the Verify the password page. I want to do it If the password has been entered within the last half hour, then don't need to enter the password again and go to the GetTest3Page. Like this:

```
RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    var func = Get.arguments ?? () {};
    if (func is Function) {
      func.call();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But how do I stop the current route, not go to `GetTest2Page` and then to `GetTest3Page`?
I try the code like this, but it throws an error

```
@override
GetPage? onPageCalled(GetPage? page) {
    return null;
}
```

What should I do? Please help me!

I asked `ChatGPT`, but the answer was wrong;
I try to Google it, but no one needs anything like me.

Here is my code:

```
runApp(
  GetMaterialApp(
    getPages: [
      GetPage(
        name: GetTestPage.name,
        page: () => GetTestPage(),
      ),
      GetPage(
        name: GetTest2Page.name,
        page: () => GetTest2Page(),
        middlewares: [SystemPasswordMiddleware()]
      ),
      GetPage(
        name: GetTest3Page.name,
        page: () => GetTest3Page(),
      ),
    ],
    initialRoute: GetTestPage.name,
  ),
);
```

Here is my Middleware code:

```
class SystemPasswordMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    // print('redirect');
    var func = Get.arguments ?? () {};
    if (func is Function) {
      func.call();
    }
    RouteSettings(name: GetTest3Page.name);
    return null;
  }

  @override
  GetPage? onPageCalled(GetPage? page) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And this is my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY3uu.png)

If I use this:

```
@override
GetPage? onPageCalled(GetPage? page) {
    return super.onPageCalled(page);
}
```

It works but does not stop the `Test2page`.

Comment: Could you share the error that you get? Thanks

Comment: sir, I edit the question.please read it again